# HTML Placeholder doesn't appear on masked input type

Tags: jquery, html, placeholder

I'm using mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder and everything works very well in all versions of browser which is most important for me, because the most of our clients uses IE7,8.

But as usual there is issues in Internet Explorer. I have one input type precisely it is phone number which is masked and when I was turned off masking of that field placeholder appear in IE, in otherwise it doesn't appear. How I can fix it to work on a  elements which have a mask.

Here is code:

```
 <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number_btd"  value="<?php echo $phone_number; ?>" placeholder="Phone Number"/>


$("#phone_number_btd").mask("(999) 999-9999? x9999");
```

and below is code to call a placeholder functionality:

```
     (jQuery)('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
          input.val('');
          input.removeClass('placeholder');
        }
      }).blur(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
          input.addClass('placeholder');
          input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
        }
      }).blur();
```

Comment: Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately that is to difficult because I need to include a lot of files, so I found a solution. It's not best way but it works. I ignore masking if the browser is Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The following script completely resolved the issue I was having with "Business Phone" not showing up in MSIE 9 through 11. Hope this helps.

Placeholders.js is a JavaScript polyfill for the HTML5 placeholder attribute. It's lightweight, has zero dependencies and works in pretty much any browser you can imagine.

```
https://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/

    <script src="CHANGE-TO-PATH-AFTER-DOWNLOADED/placeholders.min.js"></script>

    <section>
    <label class="">
    <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Business Phone">
    </label>
    </section>


    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function()
     {
      // Masking
         $("#phone").mask('(999) 999-9999', {placeholder:'X'});
      // $("#date").mask('99/99/9999', {placeholder:'X'});
      // $("#card").mask('9999-9999-9999-9999', {placeholder:'X'});
      // $("#serial").mask('***-***-***-***-***-***', {placeholder:'_'});
      // $("#tax").mask('99-9999999', {placeholder:'X'});
     });            
    </script>
```

Comment: With {placeholder: 'X'}, maskedInput works but Placeholders.js doesn't, without it Placeholders.js works, but maskedInput doesn't. :/